# view does not exist when trying to include a built in login/logout system in django views

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

The code is

```
#urls.py

from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from employees import views
from schdeules import views
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout'), 
url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name':    'admin/login.html'}), 
url(r'^accounts/$', 'django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to', {'url': '/'}), 
url(r'^accounts/profile/$', 'django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to', {'url': '/'}),
)

#views.py 
# Create your views here.
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render
@login_required
def home(request):
  welecome = 'hai welcome to opas'
  context = {'temp_var': welecome}
  return render(request, 'schdeules/home.html')

and iam getting an error

Exception Type: ViewDoesNotExist at /opas/
Exception Value: Could not import django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to. Parent module   django.views.generic.simple does not exist.
```

i want to use django default login and logout modules.
if successfully logged in then i want to redirect to home page. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The function-based generic view `redirect_to` was deprecated in Django 1.3, and removed in Django 1.5. Use the class-based generic view [`RedirectView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/flattened-index/#redirectview) instead.

```
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

urlpaterns = ('',
...
    url(r'^accounts/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/')), 
    url(r'^accounts/profile/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/')),
)
```

Note that you don't have to include url patterns for `/accounts/` and `/accounts/profile/`. You may be better to set [`LOGIN_REDIRECT_VIEW`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url) in your settings, so that users are redirected straight to the home page after logging in.

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_VIEW = 'home' # using a named url pattern requires Django 1.5 or later
```

Comment: in which urls.py i have to add thz code.either in app urls.py or project urls.py

Comment: I added thz code in app urls.py.but it is showing home page without login authentication

Comment: You should be able to include those url patterns in any `urls.py`, but if it's not working, it's probably easiest to put them in your project's `urls.py`. If the home page is displaying then either the user is already logged in, or the view displaying the home page is not using the `login_required` decorator. `LOGIN_REDIRECT_VIEW` is a setting, so belongs in `settings.py`.